# Modifying S3 Object will reflect on cloudfront if everything is already setup

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cache-invalidation

Lets assume I have setup s3 bucket, and Cloudfront distrib. pointing to it. 
There is a CSS File and I am able to do get request on the CSS via Cloudfront.

Now If make updates to CSS and upload to s3 bucket, will it work without a Cloudfront Cache invalidation or should I cache invalidate on Cloudfront.

Could someone throw light on this.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to invalidate the cache or wait for the object to expire from the cache (based on Cache-Control response associated with the object as constrained by CloudFront Min/Default/Max TTL settings) before you can be sure that subsequent requests will always see the new object.

There is no content push or any kind of automatic invalidation integration from S3 to CloudFront, and one of those would be required for this to be transparent and immediate.